# mt19937 and normal distribution

Tags: c++, random, normal-distribution, mt19937

Helo there!
I am just starting to code in C++ and I'm not sure how to use random numbers generators properly. For example I need numbers from range [0,30000], how to make sure that I won't get only small numbers from my range.
My function:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 rng(rd());
int myRand(int i) {
    std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(30, 1500);
    double temp=distribution(rng);
    if(temp<0){
        temp*=(-1);
    }
    return (int) std::round(temp)%i;
}
```

Would you mind helping me to configure normal_distribution properly?

Comment: That's a really really weird distribution that you're calculating there. What is the intended distribution?

Comment: Being completely honest with you, I ve found this distribution on some site. All I need is a lot of numbers from [0,n] . Every number should have the same probability to be chosen.

Comment: That's built in, see `uniform_int_distribution`.

Comment: Could you link the site you have found this?

Answer (score 4):

The term "normal distribution" does not mean a "regular distribution". It means a [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), as defined by mathematics. That's not what you want.

What you're looking for is a [`uniform_real_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution), which spits out floats on a given range. However, it only does this on a half-open range.

```
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0, 30000);
double temp=distribution(rng);
```

This may return 0, but it will never return 30000.

If you want integers over a closed range, you can use `uniform_int_distribution`.

Comment: Worth pointing out that `uniform_int_distribution` has a closed range.